# rails + devise redirect to home after timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise 1.4.0.  What I need is to configure the url to root after the session has timed out ( instead of redirecting to login).
Anybody know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `after_sign_out_path_for` method. Add this method in your `ApplicationController` as a `private` method:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

Take a look at [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out) for details.

Comment: This worked for me , for some extent . I am looking for the user to redirect to a page they were in before the session timeout and login back . But this above function will store the session when you log out explicitly and login back and visit other page and once the timeout . it redirects to page you werein in when you logged out not to the once you were in when timeout .

Comment: This answer regards redirection after user sign out not session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which I am using for this purpose.

```
In application_controller.rb

private  
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 params[:back].nil? ? home_path : params[:back]
end
```

You want to set up home_path in routes.rb file.This will override the default routing.